# Data Transformations in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

Hi I have a dataset with following values

```
ID1 | ID2
123 | abc123 
456 | abc123
123 | NA
456 | NA
```

In the above table, I want to change the value of NA into abc123 using a select PostgreSQL query.

```
ID1 | ID2
123 | abc123 
456 | abc123
123 | abc123
456 | abc123
```

Comment: You know update? What have you tried?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Laurenz's answer handles what it seems like you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#functions-case) expression in the `SELECT` list, something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id2 = 'NA' THEN 'abc123' ELSE id2 END
```

Comment: I cannot add abc123 as replacement as it needs to be generic

Comment: Well, you describe your question better. It is hard to guess what you really want...